# Как сохранить 3d массив строк с помощью Shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, android-shared-preferences

Я новичок в Flutter и делаю что-то вроде календаря, где все созданные пользователем Ивенты хранятся в 3d массиве `IventList[month][day][numOfIvent]`. Я пробую закодировать массив в строку, для того чтобы сохранить её через Shared preferences, а потом декодировать её обратно при получении данных методами `jsonEncode` и `jsonDecode`. Но при декодировании полученного массива я получаю ошибку `error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [buzhigsr_app] lib\calender.dart:35)`. Может быть кто-нибудь знает как убрать эту ошибку или иным способом сохранить массив через Shared preferences? Заранее всем спасибо.

```
  List tList = List.generate(12, (m) => List.generate(31, (d) => List.generate(40, (i) => "")));
  getAndSendData() async{
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setString('key', jsonEncode(tList));
  tList = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('key'));
  }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Простыми словами ошибка
*: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'*

возникает когда переменной типа String присваевается значение типа String или null; исправление выглядит примерно так:

```
String pureStr = nullOrStr!;
```